# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) cant find any solution

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to access localhost but getting this error i am not using any password but still getting error my config.in file also has no password so if anyone know please help

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index.php on line 12
> Sorry we failed to connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
<?php
    // INSERT INTO `notes` (`sno`, `title`, `description`, `tstamp`) VALUES (NULL, 'But Books', 'Please buy books from Store', current_timestamp());
    $insert = false;
    $update = false;
    $delete = false;
    // Connect to the Database 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "notes";
    
    // Create a connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    
    // Die if connection was not successful
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Sorry we failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: i have checked my config.in file to see if it has any password ,changed the connection variables but was not succesfull